# Unexpected result in OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I stumbled upon this while running a test case set to order emails alphabeticly.

```
var test1 = new List<string>
{
    "ZZZ", "AAA", "BBB"
};

var result1 = test1.OrderBy(t => t).ToList();
// Expected: AAA, BBB, ZZZ
// Result: BBB, ZZZ, AAA

var test2 = new List<string>
{
    "ZK", "AB", "BA"
};

var result2 = test2.OrderBy(t => t).ToList();
// Expected: AB, BA, ZK
// Result: AB, BA, ZK
```

I get this behavior both in .Net 4.6.1 and .Net Core 1.0, 2.0 and 2.1.

Am I missing something here or is this indeed a weird bug?

Comment: I've copied your code, pasted and it works as expected. How you checking the result?

Comment: yes as "SeM" said, your code works as intended. how did u check your result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the culture you are running it under

`AA` will be interpreted as `Å` in some cultures, and that is lexically after both `Z` and `B`

Use the overload that takes an `IComparer<_>` to override the behavior.

Comment: test2.OrderBy(t => t,StringComparer.InvariantCulture)